# Get Memory Card Root(path) in J2me

Tags: java, java-me, lwuit

I want to get memory card path from device. By using following statement we can get path but i want to know is this method will work for all manufactures or only for nokia?

```
 System.getProperty("fileconn.dir.memorycard");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to get memory card path from device. By using following statement we can get path but i want to know is this method will work for all manufactures or only for nokia?

System.getProperty("fileconn.dir.memorycard");

Yes, this method will work for all manufactures, Samsung, LG, Sony...etc

Comment: I just tried it in the Java ME Platform SDK 3.0, and it returned null. Now that may be because the External Events Generator doesn't distinguish whether mounted filesystems are memory cards or some other form of storage; but it's worth noting that your app won't work in the emulator if you rely on this property.

Answer (score 2):

It will work for many manufacturers and many of their phones, but not all so your app should be prepared for situations where this call will return nothing or just wrong URL.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you can take a look here.
[FileConnection](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/systems/index-156490.html)

Don't forget to put the permissions to write and read from file, in the jad manifest.